# SQL: Specific distinct columns out of 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table with 2 columns:

```
ZahlBed | Bez
------------------------------------------------------
60      | 60 Tage betto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften
60      | 60 Tage netto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften
60      | ne
14      | 14 Tage netto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften
.
.
.
```

Now we want to search for a given string (i.e. 60) in both columns and weight the result with a SortFactor:

The first Statement will search for '60' in 'ZahlBed' and has the sortfactor 10.
The second searches for '%60%' and will give us 600 or so and has the sortfactor 11.
The third searches for '%60%' in the 'Bez'-column, sortfactor 20.
The last searches for 60 in the 'Bez'-column, sortfactor 15.
At the end, it will order it by the SortFactor.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 ZahlBed,Bez,SortFactor FROM ((
SELECT ZahlBed,Bez ,10 AS SortFactor FROM XXAV_CMCTermOfPayment WHERE  (ZahlBed LIKE 60) ) UNION  
SELECT ZahlBed,Bez ,11 AS SortFactor FROM XXAV_CMCTermOfPayment WHERE ZahlBed  LIKE  '%60%' AND LEN(ZahlBed) <> LEN('60')  UNION  
SELECT ZahlBed,Bez ,20 AS SortFactor FROM XXAV_CMCTermOfPayment WHERE Bez  LIKE  '%60%'   UNION  
SELECT ZahlBed,Bez ,15 AS SortFactor FROM XXAV_CMCTermOfPayment WHERE Bez  LIKE  60)  A  
ORDER BY SortFactor ASC
```

The expected Result is this:

```
ZahlBed | Bez                                          | SortFactor
-------------------------------------------------------------------
60      | 60 Tage betto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | ...
60      | 60 Tage netto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | ...
60      | ne                                           | ...
```

Instead we are getting this:

```
ZahlBed | Bez                                          | SortFactor
--------------------------------------------------------------------
60      | 60 Tage betto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | 10
60      | 60 Tage netto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | 10
60      | ne                                           | 10
60      | 60 Tage betto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | 20
60      | 60 Tage netto. Für Rechnungen & Gutschriften | 20
```

Our Problem now is, that we are getting duplicates in the columns 'ZahlBed' and 'Bez' but not in 'SortFactor'.

How can we only get distinct values?

Comment: `LIKE '%60%'` will match on the same rows as `LIKE 60` - so you are getting duplicates there.  They remain even though you use a `distinct` because you have added the sortfactor column and that makes them different

Comment: Yes, I know. But I Need the `SortFactor` to order the result. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression to calculate your `SortFactor` once for each row instead:

```
select top 20 
    ZahlBed
  , Bez
  , SortFactor
from (
  select 
      ZahlBed
    , Bez 
    , case 
        when ZahlBed like 60 then 10
        when ZahlBed  like '%60%' and len(ZahlBed) <> len('60') then 11
        when Bez like '%60%' then 15
        when Bez like 60 then 20
        else -1
        end as SortFactor
  from xxav_cmctermOfPayment
  ) s
where SortFactor > 0
order by SortFactor
```

Alternately, you could aggregate your results with `group by` and take the `min(SortFactor)`:

```
select top 20 
    ZahlBed
  , Bez
  , min(SortFactor) as SortFactor
from (select ZahlBed, Bez, 10 as SortFactor from xxav_cmctermOfPayment where (ZahlBed like 60) 
union select ZahlBed, Bez, 11 as SortFactor from xxav_cmctermOfPayment where ZahlBed  like '%60%' and len(ZahlBed) <> len('60')
union select ZahlBed, Bez, 20 as SortFactor from xxav_cmctermOfPayment where Bez  like '%60%'
union select ZahlBed, Bez, 15 as SortFactor from xxav_cmctermOfPayment where Bez  like 60
)  A  
group by ZahlBed, Bez
order by min(SortFactor) asc
```

rextester demo (SQL Server): http://rextester.com/WPIDS94742

rextester demo (Oracle): http://rextester.com/RUDA52769

Comment: I this there should be a where clause for inner query for all the conditions which you used in case, to limit the result like OP did with UNION?

Comment: @Utsav The `where` clauses moved to the `case` expression, and the same records would be removed by having the final `where SortFactor > 0`.

Comment: Nice. I was wondering why are you saying `sortfactor>0`. Makes sense now. Also my answer is basically moot now.

Comment: Both solutions work like a Charme! I prefer the first one, because of the case function. Do you know which one is faster? Thank you!

Comment: @F.Baum I would assume that the first one is faster as it will only do a single table scan, and some of the `like` expressions aren't sargable meaning they would result in index scans anyway. But, every case is different, and if you really want to know you can test each version and compare performance with `set statistics time, io on;` and compare execution plans.

Comment: @F.Baum Added rextester demos for SQL Server and Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Try running this.

```
select top 20 ZahlBed, Bez, SortFactor from
    (
    select ZahlBed,Bez, 
        case 
        when (ZahlBed LIKE 60) then 10
        when ZahlBed  LIKE  '%60%' AND LEN(ZahlBed) <> LEN('60') then 11
        when Bez  LIKE  '%60%' then 20
        when Bez  LIKE  60 then 15 
        end
    as sortFactor
    from XXAV_CMCTermOfPayment
    where 
        (
            ZahlBed LIKE 60
            or
            (ZahlBed  LIKE  '%60%' AND LEN(ZahlBed) <> LEN('60') )
            or
            Bez  LIKE  '%60%'
            or
            Bez  LIKE  60
        )
    ) t 
order by SortFactor
```